# Simulate random position mouse events in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent

I want to build a very rough app which will simulate mouse clicks every 10th of a second at random places on the entire screen.  I was thinking of building this in Cocoa/Objective-C.  Can anyone point me in a direction of research?

Answer (score 1):

To do something every 1/10th of a second, you need an [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

To simulate mouse clicks, you need [`CGEventCreateMouseEvent()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCFCJGH) in conjunction with [`CGEventPost()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCEDCEA).

To generate random numbers, you need [`arc4random()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/arc4random.3.html)